# How to find difference in minute up to two decimal between two column in Oracle where both column datatype is date?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to subtract the column `entrystarttime` from column `entryfinishtime` in the `entry` table so as to get the difference in minutes up to two decimal places in Oracle database.

Both columns' datatype is date.
An example of what's inserted into the `entry` table is

```
INSERT INTO entry(entrystarttime,entryfinishtime) 
VALUES (TO_DATE('01-feb-2018:10:00:00 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy:hh:mi:ss am'),
    TO_DATE('01-feb-2018:10:59:30 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy:hh:mi:ss am');
```

Here is what I attempted so far

```
select  to_date(entryfinishtime, 'dd-mon-yyyy:hh:mi:ss am') - to_date(entrystarttime, 'dd-mon-yyyy:hh:mi:ss am')from entry;
```

But all I get are rows of 0s.
Like this

```
TO_DATE(ENTRYFINISHTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY:HH:MI:SSAM')-TO_DATE(ENTRYSTARTTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY:HH:MI:SSAM')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your values are already dates, so there is no need to convert them again.  To get the difference in minutes:

```
select (entryfinishtime - entrystarttime) * 24 * 60
```

To get this to two decimal places:

```
select round((entryfinishtime - entrystarttime) * 24 * 60, 2)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=516cc444a81206f21e2aec00ad4477cd) is a db<>fiddle.